# How to make windows (8.1) not generate thumbnails every time I browse into a folder?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cache, thumbnails

every single time I browse into a photo or video folder, it regenerates the thumbnails on every file, isn't this the whole point of caching thumbnails, so it don't happen every single time!
this is very frustrating and tiresome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the answer [Thumbnail Cache Automatic Deletion Problem in Windows](http://www.askvg.com/fix-thumbnail-cache-automatic-deletion-problem-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel > Folder Options > View > Always show icons, never thumbnails

Comment: not never, just not every single time.

Comment: Perhaps it's turned off then, check the setting and turn it on if so. If it's disabled it wouldn't be creating the thumbnail caches. And cycling it might "unstick" it if it's not working right.